# Text formatting in a table

Tags: html

I'm trying to format this HTML table so that the Total: and resulting dollar amount are aligned under the Price Total column:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5jkF.png)

```
    <table style="font-size: 12px; font-family: sans-serif; height: 106px;" width="750" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><strong>SKU</strong></td>
<td><strong>Quantity</strong></td>
<td><strong>Price Each</strong></td>
<td><strong>Price Total</strong></td>
</tr>
<!--
         #set($total = $utils.newBigDecimal("0.00"))
         #foreach($lineItem in $record.lineItems)
            #set($item = $scriptOutput.itemMap.get($lineItem.sku))
            #set($quantityBigDecimal = "")
            #set($quantityBigDecimal = $utils.newBigDecimal($lineItem.orderedQty.toString()))
            #if($lineItem.unitCost)
               #set($extended = $lineItem.unitCost.multiply($quantityBigDecimal))
               #set($total = $total.add($extended))
         #end
      -->
<tr>
<td>$lineItem.sku</td>
<td>$lineItem.orderedQty</td>
<td>$lineItem.unitCost</td>
<td><span id="autocomplete"><span id="autocomplete-delimiter">$</span></span><span style="text-align: right;">$utils.nvl($utils.formatMoney($lineItem.unitCost), "--")</span></td>

</tr>
<!--
        #end
      -->
<tr>
<td style="font-weight: bold; border-top: 1px solid black; text-align: center; " colspan="4">Total: $utils.formatMoney($total)</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I've tried non-breaking space on the last td to try to "shift" the total text and amount over, tried making row I'm trying to shirt a tfooter, and various align and align-text style elements, but no luck.

I'm very new to HTML, so I'm positive there's something I don't know about that I should be doing, but with my limited experience, I'm finding my searches not turning any useful returns either.

Please help me get on track to adjusting this formatting.

Comment: Please include rendered HTML rather than code in some unknown template language that works off of data we don't have access to.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<table style="font-size: 12px; font-family: sans-serif; height: 106px;" width="750" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><strong>SKU</strong></td>
<td><strong>Quantity</strong></td>
<td><strong>Price Each</strong></td>
<td><strong>Price Total</strong></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>77-1F</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>6.1706</td>
<td><span id="autocomplete"><span id="autocomplete-delimiter">$</span></span><span style="text-align: right;">6.17</span></td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td style="font-weight: bold; border-top: 1px solid black;" >Total: 14.01</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```